Request for Price Estimates on Solar Monocrystalline Double Busbar 540W Panels and Related Components EXW Dubai, UAE
I am looking for assistance in estimating the best available prices from major manufacturers for the following components, with delivery terms EXW Dubai, UAE:

Solar monocrystalline double busbar 540W panels
Integrated inverters.
Batteries of different types
The system proposed is a 15 KW system
I found a price of around $100 per panel, inverters 60 amp at 120$ and batteries 200Ah gel type at 150$ here in the UAE, but I believe this is higher compared to other markets like China. Can anyone provide recent price estimates or share insights on better pricing available?


Hi Ahmed, I don't think this is on-topic here.
